# Running an SQL Script file and having issues printing the Current_Orders table cant understand the errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to prepare and execute a script file to create and populate a relational database in Oracle with data about `customers`, `current orders`, and `products`. These are the relationships: Each customer can place any number of current orders and each current order is placed by one customer.Each current order is for one product but each product can be in any number of
current orders.

I can't figure out the errors when running this script. The Customer and Products table are successfully filled, but the Current_Orders table is not. There are a few error codes that appear when I run it but I am not understanding them as I am fairly new to SQL. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! `ORA-00001`, `ORA-00955`, `ORA-02449`.

```
drop table Customer;
drop table Current_Orders;
drop table Products;

create table Customer
(Customer_Number integer not null, 
 Customer_Name char(20) not null,
 Customer_City char(20) not null,
 PRIMARY KEY(Customer_Number));

create table Products
(Product_Number integer not null,
 Product_Description char(20) not null,
 Unit_Price integer not null,
 PRIMARY KEY (Product_Number));

create table Current_Orders
(Order_Number integer not null,
 Order_Date date not null,
 Shipping_Method char(20) not null,
 Product_Number integer not null,
 Quantity_Ordered integer not null,
 Customer_Number integer not null,
 PRIMARY KEY(Order_Number), FOREIGN KEY(Customer_Number) 
 references Customer(Customer_Number) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
 FOREIGN KEY(Product_Number) references Products(Product_Number) 
 ON DELETE CASCADE); 

insert into Customer
values (1, 'Khizur Sheikh', 'Milpitas');
insert into Customer
values (2, 'Fatima Sheikh', 'Fremont');
insert into Customer
values (3, 'Syed Sheikh', 'Davis');
insert into Customer
values (4, 'Mohammed Sheikh', 'Oakland');
insert into Customer
values (5, 'Ali Sheikh', 'Dublin');  

insert into Products
values (6, 'iphone', 300);
insert into Products
values (7, 'ipad', 400);
insert into Products
values (8, 'imac', 500);
insert into Products
values (9, 'ipod', 600);
insert into Products
values (10, 'ihome', 700);
insert into Products
values (11, 'apple', 800);
insert into Products
values (12, 'banana', 900);
insert into Products
values (13, 'orange', 1000);
insert into Products
values (14, 'grape', 1100);
insert into Products
values (15, 'avocado', 1200);
insert into Products
values (16, 'bread', 1300);
insert into Products
values (17, 'muffin', 1400);
insert into Products
values (18, 'cheese', 1500);
insert into Products
values (19, 'milk', 1600);
insert into Products
values (20, 'brownies', 1700);
insert into Products
values (21, 'candy', 1800);
insert into Products
values (22, 'soup', 1900);
insert into Products
values (23, 'strawberry', 11000);
insert into Products
values (24, 'cookies', 50);
insert into Products
values (25, 'chocolate', 10);

insert into Current_Orders
values (26, '22-oct-2017', 'truck', 6, 1, 1); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (27, '22-nov-2017', 'ship', 7, 1, 2); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (28, '22-dec-2017', 'train', 8, 3, 3); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (29, '22-jan-2017', 'truck', 9, 2, 4); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (30, '22-feb-2017', 'train', 10, 1, 5); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (31, '22-mar-2017', 'truck', 12, 4, 2); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (32, '22-apr-2017', 'plane', 17, 7, 4); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (33, '22-may-2017', 'train', 19, 1, 5); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (34, '22-jun-2017', 'ship', 22, 3, 2); 
insert into Current_Orders
values (35, '22-jan-2017', 'ship', 21, 4, 3); 

commit;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "having issues printing the current_orders table". Also it would help if you matched each error message to the line number in the script.

Answer (score 1):

All the commands in your script work fine while running for the first time. However Issue seems to occur when you run the `DROP TABLE` statements on second and successive executions when table exists and has data.

```
drop table Customer;
drop table Current_Orders;
```

> Error report - ORA-02449: unique/primary keys in table referenced by
>   foreign keys
>   02449. 00000 -  "unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to drop a table with unique or
>              primary keys referenced by foreign keys in another table.
>   *Action:   Before performing the above operations the table, drop the
>              foreign key constraints in other tables.

I see you have defined a `FOREIGN KEY` on the column `Customer_Number`

```
FOREIGN KEY(Customer_Number) 
 references Customer(Customer_Number) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So, when you try to `DROP` from Table `Customer` before `Current_Orders` , you are basically deleting parent record before deleting the child record which is not allowed. `ORA-00955` and `ORA-00001` occur as a consequence.

So, follow this order to drop tables in your script.

```
drop table Current_Orders;
drop table Products;
drop table Customer;
```

Comment: or simply use `drop table .. cascade constraints`